# Auto refresh using xajax (and MooTools?)

Tags: php, html, css, mootools, xajax

For the purpose of testing (and making this question simpler) I have been using xajax to output a random number into a `DIV` on the page.

```
$output=rand(20,40);

$ajax_resp->assign('container','innerHTML', $output);
```

After the `DIV` container is loaded, I also load 1 line of Javascript to call the xajax function.

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  xajax_refresh().periodical(2000);
</script>
```

As you can see, I'm using the MooTools function called `periodical()` to call the function again after x milleseconds. It calls the function fine at first, but not again.

It doesn't automatically refresh. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning a periodical to `xajax_refresh` function, you are calling that function (with `xajax_refresh()`). For instance, you're assigning its returned value to periodical (It can be everything, but nothing happens because that returned value is not a function :) ).

Therefore, the solution is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  xajax_refresh.periodical(2000);
</script>
```

Comment: mmm.. kinda weird.. try to put xajax_refresh() call inside a custom function 'foo' and try to assign a periodical to that foo.. foo.periodical(2000)

Comment: It works! I set the periodical value to 4000 and expected it to first load `xajax_refresh` **then** repeat the call, but it doesn't. I now have `xajax_refresh` called before the periodical call, so it's all good. Thanks for your help.